# Remove column(s) with overrepresented categorical values

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataset like below:

```
data <- data.frame(
  Col1 = c("id1", "id2", "id3", "id4","id5",  "id6", "id7", "id8"),
  Col2 = c("A", "Bc", "A", "As", "As", "Bs", "A", "A"),
  Col3 = c("BK", "AB", "BsC", "BX", "BK", "AsB", "BC", "BX"),
  Col4 = c("CA", "XB", "CA", "SC", "CA", "CA", "CA", "SC"),
  Col5 = c("Ao", "Bu", "Ai", "Ayy", "Ao", "Byu", "Aiy", "Ay"),
  Col6 = c("Bc", "Bc", "Bc", "Bc", "Bc", "Bc", "Be", "Bd")
)

data

  Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5 Col6
1  id1    A   BK   CA   Ao   Bc
2  id2   Bc   AB   XB   Bu   Bc
3  id3    A  BsC   CA   Ai   Bc
4  id4   As   BX   SC  Ayy   Bc
5  id5   As   BK   CA   Ao   Bc
6  id6   Bs  AsB   CA  Byu   Bc
7  id7    A   BC   CA  Aiy   Be
8  id8    A   BX   SC   Ay   Bd
```

If a category is over-represented, the columns need to be omitted. For example, if the threshold is `0.74` or `74%`, the `filtered data` will remove `Col6` as category `Bc` is over-represented `(6/8=75%)`. The `filtered data` will be like the following:

```
  Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5
1  id1    A   BK   CA   Ao
2  id2   Bc   AB   XB   Bu
3  id3    A  BsC   CA   Ai
4  id4   As   BX   SC  Ayy
5  id5   As   BK   CA   Ao
6  id6   Bs  AsB   CA  Byu
7  id7    A   BC   CA  Aiy
8  id8    A   BX   SC   Ay
```

Or if the threshold is `60%`, the `filtered data` will remove `Col4` and `Col6` as category `CA` (in `Col4`) is over-represented `(5/8=62.5%)` and `Bc` (in `Col6`) is over-represented `(6/8=75%)`. The `filtered data` will be like the following:

```
  Col1 Col2 Col3 Col5
1  id1    A   BK   Ao
2  id2   Bc   AB   Bu
3  id3    A  BsC   Ai
4  id4   As   BX  Ayy
5  id5   As   BK   Ao
6  id6   Bs  AsB  Byu
7  id7    A   BC  Aiy
8  id8    A   BX   Ay
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop through columns get table frequencies, check weather smaller than threshold:

```
x = 0.74
data[ sapply(data, function(i) max(prop.table(table(i)))) < x ]
#   Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5
# 1  id1    A   BK   CA   Ao
# 2  id2   Bc   AB   XB   Bu
# 3  id3    A  BsC   CA   Ai
# 4  id4   As   BX   SC  Ayy
# 5  id5   As   BK   CA   Ao
# 6  id6   Bs  AsB   CA  Byu
# 7  id7    A   BC   CA  Aiy
# 8  id8    A   BX   SC   Ay
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution in `base`:

```
data[c(TRUE, apply(t(data[-1]),1,function(x) max(table(x)))/nrow(data) < 0.6)]

#>   Col1 Col2 Col3 Col5
#> 1  id1    A   BK   Ao
#> 2  id2   Bc   AB   Bu
#> 3  id3    A  BsC   Ai
#> 4  id4   As   BX  Ayy
#> 5  id5   As   BK   Ao
#> 6  id6   Bs  AsB  Byu
#> 7  id7    A   BC  Aiy
#> 8  id8    A   BX   Ay
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using `apply`, `any`, and `proportions`:

```
thresh <- 0.74

overrepcols <- apply(data, 2, function(x) any(proportions(table(x)) > thresh))

data[,!overrepcols]
```

Output:

```
  Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5
1  id1    A   BK   CA   Ao
2  id2   Bc   AB   XB   Bu
3  id3    A  BsC   CA   Ai
4  id4   As   BX   SC  Ayy
5  id5   As   BK   CA   Ao
6  id6   Bs  AsB   CA  Byu
7  id7    A   BC   CA  Aiy
8  id8    A   BX   SC   Ay
```

Answer (score 2):

And another answer using `dplyr` and `base`

```r
data %>%
  select_if(~max(table(.x)) / length(.x) < 0.6)

#    Col1 Col2 Col3 Col5
# 1  id1    A   BK   Ao
# 2  id2   Bc   AB   Bu
# 3  id3    A  BsC   Ai
# 4  id4   As   BX  Ayy
# 5  id5   As   BK   Ao
# 6  id6   Bs  AsB  Byu
# 7  id7    A   BC  Aiy
# 8  id8    A   BX   Ay
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use current `dplyr` synthax with `select(where(condition))`

```
library(dplyr)

threshold <- 0.74
data |> 
    select(where(\(x) !any(proportions(table(x)) > threshold)))

  Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5
1  id1    A   BK   CA   Ao
2  id2   Bc   AB   XB   Bu
3  id3    A  BsC   CA   Ai
4  id4   As   BX   SC  Ayy
5  id5   As   BK   CA   Ao
6  id6   Bs  AsB   CA  Byu
7  id7    A   BC   CA  Aiy
8  id8    A   BX   SC   Ay
```